# How to create a list dict dynamically with Python

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have this input to handle:

```
['', '', '', '', '  Huawei Integrated Access Software (MA5600T).', '  Copyright(C) Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 2002-2014. All rights reserved.', '', '  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------', '  User last login information:', '  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------', '  Access Type : Telnet ', '  IP-Address  : 1.1.1.1', '  Login  Time : 2020-12-24 11:51:33+01:00', '  Logout Time : 2020-12-24 11:51:38+01:00', '  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------', '', 'OLT-SALUZZO_01>enable', '', 'OLT-SALUZZO_01#display ont autofind all \x1b[1D\x1b[1C', '   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------', '   Number              : 1', '   F/S/P               : 0/17/7', '   Ont SN              : 485754437D85CA9E (HWTC-7D85CA9E)', '   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000', '   Loid                : ', '   Checkcode           : ', '   VendorID            : HWTC', '   Ont Version         : 159D.A', '   Ont SoftwareVersion : V5R019C00S100', '   Ont EquipmentID     : EG8145V5', '   Ont autofind time   : 2020-12-24 08:38:28+01:00', '   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------', '   Number              : 2', '   F/S/P               : 0/17/7', '   Ont SN              : 48575443A9517A9E (HWTC-A9517A9E)', '   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000', '   Loid                : ', '   Checkcode           : ', '   VendorID            : HWTC', '   Ont Version         : 159D.A', '   Ont SoftwareVersion : V5R019C00S100', '   Ont EquipmentID     : EG8145V5', "---- More ( Press 'Q' to break ) ----"]
```

and I need to create from this an output like this:

```
[{'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'SN': ' 485754437D85CA9E', 'Password': None}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}]
```

My function is something like that:

```
tn.write("display ont autofind all ".encode('utf-8') + b"\n")
return_lineid = tn.read_until('The number of GPON'.encode('utf-8'), 3).decode('utf-8')
data_return = return_lineid.splitlines()
autofind_list=[]
records = []
current_record = {}
for line in data_return:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:  # empty line
        records.append(current_record)
        current_record = {}
    else:
        if "F/S/P" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            current_record[key] = value
            print(current_record)
        if "Ont SN" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            value = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', value)
            current_record[key] = value
            print(current_record)
        if "Password" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            if value == '0x00000000000000000000':
                current_record[key]=None
            else:
                current_record[key] = value

        autofind_list.append(current_record.copy())

#for removing same records
seen = set()
new_l = []
for d in autofind_list:
    t = tuple(d.items())
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        new_l.append(d)

print(new_l)
```

But it returns this, I've almost reached my goal:

```
[{}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7'}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'Ont SN': '485754437D85CA9E '}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'Ont SN': '485754437D85CA9E ', 'Password': None}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'Ont SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}]
```

**But I would like to remove useless object like** `{}, {'F/S/P': '0/17/7'}`

Someone could kindly help me with this problem? or could give me an hint?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "every time something wrong, for example this"—what is the specific problem with that output? Please read [ask]. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: (Side note: neither of those are JSON, which only supports double-quoted strings and uses `null`, not `None`. I suspect you really have Python lists containing dicts.)

Comment: That output is the same every time if you read

Comment: Yes I would need a json or something similar, I think my question is quite clear

Comment: "That output is the same every time if you read"—so you're expecting us to notice the difference between "485754437D85CA9E" and "48575443A9517A9E", buried within long outputs that we need to scroll sideways to read? _Again_, please read [ask], making special note of the recommendation to "pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". The differences in those values should be _clearly indicated in your question_. And ideally you'd provide a [mcve]. There's a lot of code here that does nothing but distract.

Comment: Also, please fix your Python code. As it is currently written it will generate an `IndentationError`. How much of that is supposed to be in the body of `autofind()`? Please paste your code, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: The problem  here is that you only have _one_ `autofind_object` and you keep overwriting it. Try moving `autofind_object = {}` into your loop or changing `autofind_list.append(autofind_object)` to `autofind_list.append(autofind_object.copy())`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/354577)

Comment: @Chris thank you so much, how could I remove useless objects like {} or something like {'F/S/P': '0/17/7'} so without all parameters that I need?

Comment: @Chris could you kindly re-check my question? I've edited it...Thank you

Comment: Indent your `autofind_list.append(current_record.copy())` into the `else` block so it only runs when `line` is truthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your plan was with this `autofind_list`, but I assume it was your attempt at solving the problem that one record doesn't appear in `records`. This can be solved by simply adding the `current_record` after the loop is finished.

Then the only problem is the first empty record, happening because at the beginning there is an unnecessary empty line. This can be done by simply checking if `current_record` is filled before adding it to `records` (this also prevents problems if two empty lines are in a row).

Here is the full code:

```
records = []
current_record = {}
for line in data_return:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:  # empty line
        if current_record: # no data recorded
            records.append(current_record)
            current_record = {}
    else:
        if "F/S/P" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            current_record[key] = value
        if "Ont SN" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            value = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', value)
            current_record[key] = value
        if "Password" in line:
            key, value = line.split(':')
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            if value == '0x00000000000000000000':
                current_record[key] = None
            else:
                current_record[key] = value

if current_record:
    records.append(current_record)
```

`records` now includes the list I think you want.

---

Since your example data in the post doesn't actually represent the input you are given, in which records are separated by `----` dash-only lines, you need to replace `if not line:` with `if not line or set(line) == {'-'}:`.

Comment: it returns only a single record: [{'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'Ont SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}]

Comment: @snuz It doesn't for me. Can you maybe give an example input? Via pastebin?

Comment: it is all described in the question, the input that I need to handle it's the first thing that I wrote in the question

Comment: @snuz And that input works for me. Are you sure you have the last few lines of my answer included?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure! if I print 'records' it only prints '[{'F/S/P': '0/17/7', 'Ont SN': '48575443A9517A9E ', 'Password': None}]'

Comment: @snuz Well, can you add a `print(data_return)` and give me the ouput?

Comment: It appends only the latest current record your code

Comment: @snuz It works for me, so something on your side is wrong. Since the only error message I get from you is 'it doesn't work', I can't help you.

Comment: Where could I send you the output?

Comment: @snuz That data is in a different format. The records are separated by lines containing only dashes.

Comment: yes, I know but so why can he read the records anyway?

Comment: If I print the current_record they are ok

Comment: @snuz The code only appends to `records` on an empty line, since that is what you told me is correct.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9sHekevF this is the output if I print current_record in the loop. Anyway, the output that I need you can see on the question.

Comment: @snuz I added code to the answer. Does it work then?

Comment: @snuz Also, please update your question to contain the actual input and not what you believe the input to be.

Comment: Sorry...I would like to kindly ask you one last thing, how can I do to access the items? For example for obtaining only 0/17/7 from records?

Comment: @snuz I am not sure what you mean. You can open a new question if it is something new.

Comment: I mean obtaining a value in the list